# How to Make a HTML Text Box Unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any method to make a text box unclickable that does not involve disabling the text box or also blocking mouse hover events?

I cannot set the text box as disabled because that will disable my jQuery tool tips, and I cannot block mouse hover events either. All of the solutions I have seen have done one or the other.

To clarify a bit, the user cannot be able to select text in this box or place the typing pointer inside the box. Using labels will not work because I need it to work on password fields as well as normal text fields.

Comment: Perhaps position an invisible div above it with z-index and pos absolute, filling exactly the height and width of the text box

Comment: Won't that block hover as well as click events?

Comment: You can't use `disabled`, so presumably you can't use `readonly`? What use/function does this text `input` serve, precisely, that you don't want the user to interact with it?

Comment: It can be and currently is read only. The reason people are not supposed to be able to interact with it is because when a person hovers their mouse over the text box the browser automatically selects text in a hidden text box and displays a tooltip notifying the person that they can now simply use Ctrl+C to copy the text in the box. If a person clicks in the box it will deselect that text which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#textbox').focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Rxw/)

Comment: This does do everything I specified in the question, but still not working for my situation. I figured it out though by simply selecting the text that needed to be selected again every time the box is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but this should work.

```
<input id="noselect" value="hi there"></input>
<script>
  document.getElementById('noselect').addEventListener('focus', function()
  {
    document.getElementById('noselect').blur();
  });
  document.getElementById('noselect').style.cursor = 'default';
</script>
```